# codeigniter how to display orderid from request table with distinct values

Tags: php, codeigniter

1. how to display orderid from request table with distinct values.
2. on click on each orderid will display all orderid without distinct values
   this is my table

[image]

my model function is:

```
function show_requests()
        $this->db->from('requests');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group by for distinct.
Add this line in your query

Ex. $this->db->group_by('orderid');

Comment: Thanks @akbanu, but what i need is also to display all orderid when click on each row with orderid

Comment: for example when i click on row one with distinict values, i need to show up two rows with orderid=1  with request_id=1,2

Comment: Ok now you just pass the orderid in where condition without group by.
Ex:
$this->db->where($orderid);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

`Query : 1`  Get Distinct Order

```
function show_requests()
    $this->db->from('requests');
    $this->db->group_by('orderid');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

`Query : 2`  Get Requested Order details

```
function display_request_by_orderid($id) {
    $row = array();
    $this->db->where('orderid', $id);
    $this->db->from('requests');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row();
    } 
    return $row;
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: this is my model for view more please i need help on this: function display_request_by_orderid($id)
 {
    
  $this->db->where('orderid', $id);
  $this->db->from('requests');
   $query = $this->db->get();
  if($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
   $row = $query->row();
  }

   return $row;
 }

Comment: Please share your error message your facing this function.

Comment: i have no error but on view more i only getting one distinict value

Comment: note that `row()` only returns 1 row, not sure if that's your error but you could try using `result()`